# HTML: Images floating left?

Tags: html, css, layout, image-resizing

I wanna make a page with lots of images being shown.

```
<style>
img{margin-bottom: 3px; float: left}
</style>

<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
<img src="myimg.png">
```

It looks good if they all have the same width and height. 
But what happens when one of them has a larger size? It messes all the layout,
showing a white space that makes it look ugly.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I understand your problem, but what solution do you really want? if the heights are different, you'll have to make a decision between allowing gap spaces or not.

Comment: Will cropping of image will work for you in layouting

Answer (score 1):

why don't you put width: 150px or whatever the size you want inside that css?

```
<style>
img{margin-bottom: 3px; width: 150px; float: left}
</style>
```

Comment: it will insert unequal whitespaces in rows

Comment: wait I don't seem to get the question then... Those images aren't in a table, and also I don't see any divs with constant heights around them?

Comment: Why dont I do that? Because not all images have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit javascript you could bring them all to the same size. But it won't look much better. 
Maybe the same width and a simple repeating background which won't be annoying would be a compromise.

Comment: Maybe this would be a bit too much for just a few images?

Comment: The point was the solution/positioning of images itself not using this script.

Comment: noo, I don't want all the pictures to have the same size. I just want no white spaces regardless of the image size.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not very necessary to show the entire image you can consider placing your images in div tags, either as background images, centering them and then setting a fixed width and height for the div elements.

```
<style>
.imgpanel{
  margin-bottom: 3px; 
  float: left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  width:200px;
  height:200px; 
}
</style>


<div class="imgpanel" style="background-image:url('/images/sample.png');"></div>
<div class="imgpanel" style="background-image:url('/images/sample.png');"></div>
<div class="imgpanel" style="background-image:url('/images/sample.png');"></div>
<div class="imgpanel" style="background-image:url('/images/sample.png');"></div>
```

Or you can place the image within the div tags and set the overflow to hidden:

```
<style>
.imgpanel{
  margin-bottom: 3px; 
  float: left;
  width:200px;
  height:200px; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="imgpanel"><img src="/images/sample.png" /></div>
<div class="imgpanel"><img src="/images/sample.png" /></div>
<div class="imgpanel"><img src="/images/sample.png" /></div>
```

Optionally, you can use a thumbnail generation script to create images that are always the specific size you want, if re-sizing the image is okay. Check http://sourceforge.net for code samples of a thumbnail generator.

Answer (score 0):

### Limit sizes

```
img {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;

    border: 1px solid grey; /* show visible element size */
}
```

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/UqGW7/3/

### Fixes sizes (strech)

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    border: 1px solid grey; /* show visible element size */
}
```

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/UqGW7/4/

### Crop images (using a wrapper)

```
<span class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/592211_21253884267_736366040_q.jpg" />
</span>


.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden; /* crop larger images */

    border: 1px solid grey; /* show visible element size */

    text-align:center; /* center horizontally */
}
```

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/UqGW7/5/

Comment: I had to update the sample since one image is no longer available.